# Checking if two lists of objects are equal

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I need to compare the values of two lists of objects in VB.NET in a web application. I can't seem to find any working examples of how to do this.

I have tried the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.0

Where they implement a custom interface for doing so. But even using the exact code gives me errors.

Here is the code I'm currently trying. It's basically the same thing as Microsoft's example but using my own class:

```
Public Class ForumWithName
    Inherits IEquatable(Of ForumWithName)

    Private mForumID As Integer
    Public Property ForumID() As Integer
        Get
            Return mForumID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            mForumID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private mForumName As String
    Public Property ForumName As String
        Get
            Return mForumName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            mForumName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private mSubscribed As Boolean
    Public Property Subscribed As Boolean
        Get
            Return mSubscribed
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            mSubscribed = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Compare(ByVal other As ForumWithName) As Boolean
        If other Is Nothing Then Return False
        Return Me.ForumID = other.ForumID AndAlso Me.Subscribed = other.Subscribed
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return Compare(TryCast(obj, ForumWithName))
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return (ForumID, Subscribed).GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

This code fails to compile because of a few errors:
"Classes can inherit only from other classes"
"Predefined type 'ValueTuple(Of,) is not defined or imported."
"Visual Basic 10.0 does not support tuples"
"'GetHashCode' is not a member of '(ForumID as Integer, Subscribed as Boolean)'"

Once I get this code to work, my plan is to compare two lists of the "ForumWithName" class above.

For example(assume SubscribedsForum1 and SubscribedForums2 are both Lists(Of ForumWithName)):

```
If SubscribedForums1.SequenceEqual(SubscribedForums2) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the lists and what exactly do you mean by *Compare two lists*

Comment: @preciousbetine Updated my post. I'm trying to compare two lists of the ForumWithName object I made above. By Compare I just need to know whether their contents are the exact same or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEquatable` is an Interface, it needs to be Implemented and not inherited. (I am guessing here, but I think it's a Typo in the MSDN page you linked)

Change the class declare from:

```
Public Class ForumWithName
    Inherits IEquatable(Of ForumWithName)
```

to be

```
Public Class ForumWithName
    Implements IEquatable(Of ForumWithName)
```

Once you have done that, you will also need to add this function

```
Public Overloads Function Equals(other As ForumWithName) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of ForumWithName).Equals
    Return Compare(TryCast(other, ForumWithName))
End Function
```

To work around the problem of not being able to use Tuples, you should be able to use this:

```
Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    Return (ForumID & Subscribed).GetHashCode()
End Function
```

EDIT:

On a side note, you may want to include the properties `ForumName` and `Subscribed` in the `GetHashCode` function to check if the objects are truly equal to one another.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! After using the corrections you have here I was able to use SequenceEqual to check if the values of two separate lists of ForumWithName are equal.

Comment: @rgorr It's a pleasure to help. I also added a note on extending your `GetHashCode` function, it's optional and totally up to you are your logic to include

Comment: The example code in MS docs clearly says Inherit IEquatable. I posted a note to MS to correct this. Thank you @JayV .